# TFS integration in WebStorm (Connection opened by different user)

Tags: tfs, webstorm

I'm trying to add a team foundation server in WebStorm (I've enabled alternate credentials) but I keep getting this error :

```
"Connection to server was opened by different user".
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 5):

Issue occurs only when "User name (secondary)" is used. So **current workaround is** to not set "User name (secondary)" and use "User name (primary)" to log in.

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104231 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress (for a proper fix).